# Dynamin APN configuration for GSM

Tags: gsm

I am working on GSM modem and using ublox SARA g 350 modem for GPRS data communication.

And I am able to set pre defined apn using AT command

But my question is, Is there a way to get apn from service provider?

I should handle setting apn depending on SIM inserted by the user.

Can anyone help me to get details for this ?